# Could you explain “had it not been for”?

Tags: meaning, inversion

Could you explain the grammar of this sentence?:

...my own father would have drowned himself **had it not been for** my mother's prayers and faith.

I didn't understand the construction of this sentence. The tense in bold and its relation to the tense before. It seem like conditional but there is no **if** is there an idiom here.

Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

Conditional statements don't always need to have an *if*. *Would … have* constructions are also conditionals.

In fact, all of these sentences are conditional and mean the same thing:

- My own father **would have** drowned himself **had it not been for** my mother's prayers and faith.
- **Had it not been for** my mother's prayers and faith, my own father **would have** drowned himself.
- **If not for** my mother's prayers and faith, my own father **would have** drowned himself.
- My own father **would have** drowned himself **if not for** my mother's prayers and faith.